# pass XMLDocument, OleDbConnection and webBrowser objects by reference

Tags: c#, .net, oop, object, pass-by-reference

I have several methods that pass common .NET objects OleDbConnection, XMLDocument, webBrowser to methods that do operations on it. I am passing them as an object without ref/out keyword. Like:

```
void btn_click()
{
  OleDbConnection dbConn; XMLDocument Doc; webBrowser Browser;

  // Do operations on dbConn, Doc and Browser here

  Call(dbConn, Doc, Browser);
}

void Call(OleDbConnection dbConn, XMLDocument Doc, webBrowser Browser)
{
  // Do operations on dbConn, Doc and Browser here

  Call2(OleDbConnection dbConn, XMLDocument Doc, webBrowser Browser);
}

void Call2(OleDbConnection dbConn, XMLDocument Doc, webBrowser Browser)
{
  // Do further operations on dbConn, Doc and Browser here
}
```

These methods are called thousand of times and hence objects are passed each time. The program is working fine. None of the object is reset or re-initialized in called methods, only their property data is used. so I believe that I do not need to pass them as "ref".

My question is if I pass all of those as ref, will there be any significant performance gains, especially in database connection or webbrowser navigation? Is there any article that describes any performance gain when objects are passed as ref and when they are not?

Comment: Aren't they reference types already? I'm pretty sure `XMLDocument` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to reply to your question directly: No you will not have any significant gain by using ref: your objects are all reference type (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs(v=vs.80).aspx) and so only their own reference is passed to the functions.

Now aside from this, I see in your code that you have a bunch of methods using the same parameters, I think it would be wise to consider refactoring a bit and grouping all those methods in a (some) classes and put your connection, xml document and browser as attribute of the class. 
I think it would make your code cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This code is only to describe the question and is not a real code. Actual code is very long.